# Facebook style ajax like system no error but no result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i am currently trying to create a facebook style ajax like system. Below i have created the code like :

Jquery function for ajax call :

```
function addLikes(likeid,action) {
  $('.likebox #tutorial-'+likeid+' li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('#tutorial-'+likeid+' #rating').val((index+1));
    if(index == $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+likeid+' li').index(obj)) {
      return false;   
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: "like_process.php",
    data:'likeid='+likeid+'&action='+action,
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(){
      $('#tutorial-'+likeid+' .btn-likes').html("<img src='LoaderIcon.gif' />");
    },
    success: function(data){
      var likes = parseInt($('#likes-'+likeid).val());
      switch(action) {
        case "like":
          $('#tutorial-'+likeid+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Unlike" class="unlike" onClick="addLikes('+likeid+',\'unlike\')" />');
          likes = likes+1;
          break;
        case "unlike":
          $('#tutorial-'+likeid+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Like" class="like"  onClick="addLikes('+likeid+',\'like\')" />')
          likes = likes-1;
          break;
      }
      $('#likes-'+likeid).val(likes);
      if(likes>0) {
        $('#tutorial-'+likeid+' .label-likes').html(likes+" Like(s)");
      } else {
        $('#tutorial-'+likeid+' .label-likes').html('');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

PHP code:

```
      $str_like = 'like';
if(!empty($count)) {
$str_like = 'unlike';
}
  $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT mind.mind_id, mind.mind_user, mind.post_message, mind.like_count, mind.mind_date FROM mind LEFT JOIN friends ON (mind.mind_user = friends.hunter) OR (mind.mind_user = friends.target) WHERE ((friends.hunter = '".$muser."' AND friends.status = '1') OR (friends.target = '".$muser."' AND friends.status = '1')) OR (mind.mind_user = '".$muser."') ORDER BY mind.mind_date DESC limit $start,$limit");  
  $str='';

  if($sql!=null && $sql->num_rows>0){
   while($none = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
       $timep = $none['mind_date'];
       $count = $none['like_count'];
       $timeframe=date('c', $timep);
       $likeid = $none["mind_id"];



 $str.="<div id=\"likebox\"><div class=\"bubble-list\"><div class=\"bubble clearfix\"><img src=\"#\"><div class=\"bubble-content\"><div class=\"point\"></div><p><b>".$none['mind_user']."</b> <small> <time class=\"timeago\" datetime=\"".$timeframe."\">".$timeframe."</small></time></p><p>".$none['post_message']."</p><div id=\"tutorial-$likeid\">
<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"likes-".$none["mind_id"]."\" value=\"".$none["mind_id"]."\">
<div class=\"btn-likes\"><input type=\"button\" title=\"ucwords($str_like)\" class=\"$str_like\" onClick=\"addLikes('$likeid','$str_like')\" /></div>
</div>
</div></div></div></div></div>";
   }
   $str.="<input type='hidden' class='nextpage' value='".($page+1)."'><input type='hidden' class='isload' value='true'>";
   }else{
    $str .= "<input type='hidden' class='isload' value='false'><p>Loading Completed</p>";
   }
echo $str;
```

SQL call to like and unlike :

```
if(!empty($_POST["likeid"])) {
    switch($_POST["action"]){
        case "like":
                $mysqli->query("UPDATE `mind` SET `like_count` = like_count + 1 WHERE `mind_id` = '" . $_POST["likeid"] . "'");
            }           
        break;      
        case "unlike":
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE `mind` SET `like_count` = like_count - 1 WHERE `mind_id` = '" . $_POST["likeid"] . "'");
            }
        break;      
    }
}
```

When i click the button nothing change or it does not update database. I don't know where i am doing wrong. can anybody help me with this situation as i am stuck doing it and tried in different ways but couldn't make it.

Comment: Can you show us a demo of what you are doing?

Comment: Add an error handler, does it get triggered?

Comment: Praveen Kumar : actually i am doing the project on xampp so can't show the live demo ..... actually button is showing and click is counting too but it is not processing i can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Can you try deserializing the data and send as an object?

```
data: {
  'likeid': likeid,
  'action': action
}
```

Comment: tried that but still didn't work i guess [code]function addLikes(likeid,action) { }[/code] this call is not working onclick function ! what other method i can use instead of this ... i tried this too but still not working [code]$('#likebox').on('click', '#likebutton', function() { }[/code]

Comment: i figure out something which is whenever i put click function in any method even  $(document).on('click', '#like_button', function() it disable everything. The js file is not working for all page actually. All the other clickable buttons are disabled. How i will show you the complete code please let me know.